# Rails is URL-encoding strings I don't want encoded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting a URL back from a model:

```
newUrl = /thing?value=3&otherValue=16
```

and redirecting to it:

```
redirect_to newUrl
```

Rails is URL-encoding this so the `&` in the query renders as `&amp;`.

This encoding only seems to be happening in my spec tests.

Can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Nah, the encoding is performed by the redirect_to method.

Comment: What Rails version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 4.2. No luck.

Comment: When I tried this as a string: newUrl = '/thing?value=3&otherValue=16'. And then redirect_to newUrl it seems to work just fine. (Rails 4.1.4)

Comment: Redirect url: http://localhost:3000/thing?value=3&otherValue=16

Comment: PS: `&` -> `&amp;` is *HTML* encoding, not *URL* encoding. URL encoding would involve a bunch percent signs.